# Animating a view on and off the screen in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewanimation

I am trying to create a list of data displayed to the user.  When they click the next or previous button, or swipe on the scrollview, the view should transition off the screen from left to right or right to left depending on which button they press or the direction they swipe.  I have it working except that the view slides across the whole screen (meaning it slides over top of the buttons).

Here is the code to do the transition.  My scrollview is just a plain old view, but it is in the middle of the page, It's coordinates are (40,54,240,311) so I would like it to disappear at 280 and reappear at 40.  Like I said, it currently comes onto the screen at 0 and exits the screen at 320 (in normal portrait mode).

```
//Animate the scrollview across the screen
CATransition* animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
[[self.scrollView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

I would really like this to work like the Kindle App on the iPhone, where the user can drag the view left or right to show the next page.  I have looked into maybe making it a scroll view. So the above code slides my scrollview across the screen, and inside my scrollview I simply have some label and an image I set.

```
//set the content of the screen
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"image1.png"];
self.labelNumber.text = @"1";
self.labelText.text = @"Test";
```

A few initial ideas I have are that I need two scrollviews, and I have to transition between them, or I should make one really wide scrollview and have the data for the next or previous fact to the left or right.  But both of these seem to be bad because I have to have a bunch of duplicate controls, outlets etc on the screen.

PS this is my first time posting on this site. woot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new blank UIView that is the super view of your scroll view and the same size as your scroll view. Then you need to call clipsToBounds:YES on this new super view.

Something like:

```
UIView *blankView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 54, 240, 311)];
[newView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[scrollViewsParentView addSubview:blankView]

UIScrollView *yourScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 54, 311)];
[blankView addSubview:yourScrollView];
```

Notice the change in coordinates for "yourScrollView"? It's because its parent is now blankView.

Also, I've done your exact idea of using two UIScrollViews to show a transition between them. You have an on screen (showing) UIScrollView and an offscreen (not showing) UIScrollView and then do your animation to show the transition. In this case they would have the same parent (blankView).

You also might want to check out these UIView methods:

```
animateWithDuration:animations:
animateWithDuration:animations:completion:
animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yea, this is pretty good.  One other way that I started to play with, was I have a view that is say 1600 wide (or whatever screen width * 5 may be.  And then I hook up to the swipe left and right and long press left and right for this view.  I then have the subviews on this view at left 0, 320, 640, etc.  As I move along the axis, the other view will come into play.  I did this on www.oplanner.net, and iphone app in the store, and it worked out pretty nicely.